# Updating and pushing an array to mongo collection

Tags: php, database, mongodb

Hello all I am trying to create a query in order to update user's by adding another product in MongoDB.

The structure of the table `orders` is:

```
{
  "username": "mike",
  "products": [
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "61f14c42855800006f003062"
      },
      "number": "3",
      "name": "Honduras",
      "price": 7,
      "stock": 10
    }
  ],
  "status": "UNPAID"
}
```

***My query in PHP code*** is the following:

```
$collection -> updateOne(
  "username"=>"$username",'$push'=>["products" => "$json"]
);
```

*But I get the same error everytime:*

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token "=>", expecting ")"
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: change `'$push'` to `$push`

Comment: @executable Still the same error.

Comment: You need to wrap the statement in an array: `updaeOne([ "username" => ..., '$push' => ...])`. Right now, you're trying to use PHP array syntax `=>` outside of an array (syntax error)

Comment: @M.Eriksson Hey. I changed the query to: **updateOne(["username"=>"$username",'$push'=>["products" => "$json"]]);** and the error that I got is: **Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function MongoDB\Collection::updateOne(), 1 passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\eCoffeeGrinder\assets\php\add_to_cart.php on line 28 and at least 2 expected**

Comment: Look at the answer you got below. I was more focusing on the syntax error than Mongos methods. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i use a third party service/library to do that - MongoDBDriverManager PHP library

```
<?php

    $query = new MongoDBDriverBulkWrite;
    $query->update(
       ['username' => $username],
       ['$set' => ['products' => $json]],
    );

    $db_manager = new MongoDBDriverManager('mongodb://localhost:27017');
    $dbresult= $manager->executeBulkWrite('dbname.orders', $query);

?>
```

you can get more understanding i get my resources from here..

https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/php/